# Memory Leak Detection File Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, memory-leaks, crtdbg.h

I have a program that is supposed to output info on its memory leaks. However, it is not working. Following is the program:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    FILE *out_file;
    int *a = new int;

    //Redirect the error stream to a file.
    freopen_s (&out_file, "Memory Leaks.txt", "w", stderr);

    //Turn on debugging for memory leaks. This is automatically turned off when the build is Release.
    _CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
    _CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
    _CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);

    return 0;
}
```

I am building in the DEBUG version, so the functions shouldn't be ignored. The compiler I am using is Visual Studio 2010. The program only creates a file "Memory Leaks.txt" but there is no content in the file. Any thoughts?

--EDIT--

I have updated the program to use a "proper File Handle" as suggested. The program still outputs nothing to the file.

--EDIT--

The problem was with closing the file. The following code now works.

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HANDLE hLogFile;
    int *a;

    //Open a file for output.
    hLogFile = CreateFile ("Memory Leaks.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    //Turn on debugging for memory leaks. This is automatically turned off when the build is Release.
    _CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_WARN, hLogFile);
    _CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_ERROR, hLogFile);
    _CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_ASSERT, hLogFile);

    //Create a memory leak.
    a = new int;

    //Don't close this file. Closing the file will cause the report not to be outputted.
    //CloseHandle(hLogFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know these APIs at all, but seems strange that you're operating on `stdout` but passing flags with names containing `STDERR`.

Comment: Good catch. I changed that, but the output didn't change

Comment: The other thing I find puzzling is that you're apparently activating debug checks _after_ you've allocated the memory you're leaking. Just feels strange.

Comment: Well, the thing is, if I specify to output to `_CRT_MODE_DEBUG`, there isn't a problem, even if I allocated the memory before I activate debug checks.

Comment: Did you try the example specified here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is getting the output to a file, not specifying which type of output I want.

Comment: Do avoid closing the log file **before** the leak report is generated.  In other words, don't close the file.

Comment: OK, that seemed to work.

Comment: I'm upvoting everyone who answered for their contributions, and also marking JasonD as answer because his code was correct.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I should make that explicit in my answer...

Comment: If you solved the problem in some way that's not covered in an existing answer, _post your own answer_ detailing the final solution, and accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop tying to redirect stderr *or* stdout in a GUI Windows app, and open a proper File Handle. it's a one-liner.

```
HANDLE hLogFile = CreateFile(L"Memory Leaks.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
  NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

//Turn on debugging for memory leaks. This is automatically turned off when the build is Release.
_CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
_CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_WARN, hLogFile);
_CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_ERROR, hLogFile);
_CrtSetReportMode (_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile (_CRT_ASSERT, hLogFile);
```

And don't close the HANDLE before the reports are actually generated!

Answer (score 0):

Should be used to output stream **stderr**.

```
//Redirect the error stream to a file.
freopen_s (&out_file, "Memory Leaks.txt", "w", stderr);
```

Example can be found: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a68f826y%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
#include < crtdbg.h >
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
```